# In Vue, how can I batch a bunch of changes to a DOM element?

Tags: vuejs2

I'm doing an animation, where a thumbnail blows up to take up the whole screen. The first step is to get the element, change it's position to absolute and assign explicitly the dimensions and position that it's currently occupying, using a style object. Then I do my animation.

Most of the time it works nicely, but I seem to be getting DOM renders that catch my element in an intermediate state, it's position changed to absolute but the dimensions not set. In Vue, is there a way of grouping into a single batch a bunch of updates to an element?

```
var me = this;
var outer = this.$refs.outer;
if (!this.vueStore.previewing) {
    var rect = outer.getBoundingClientRect();
    this.elStyle.height = rect.bottom - rect.top;
    this.elStyle.width = rect.right - rect.left;
    this.elStyle.top = rect.top;
    this.elStyle.left = rect.left;
    this.elStyle.zIndex = 100;
    this.elStyle.position = 'absolute';
    this.elStyle.transition = 'all 0.5s ease-in-out';
    setTimeout(function () {
        this.elStyle.top = this.vueStore.contentRect.top;
        this.elStyle.left = this.vueStore.contentRect.left;
        this.elStyle.height = this.vueStore.contentRect.bottom;
        this.elStyle.width = this.vueStore.contentRect.right;
    }, 300);
} else {...
```

Comment: My guess is that setting the transition first would be actually enough to fix your issue. Even if some values start transforming early, the others will catch up early enough. Accepted answer is much more robust than that, of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should assign elStyle in 1 time

```
var me = this;
var outer = this.$refs.outer;
if (!this.vueStore.previewing) {
    var rect = outer.getBoundingClientRect();
    me.elStyle = Object.assign({}, me.elStyle, {
      height: rect.bottom - rect.top,
      width: rect.right - rect.left,
      top: rect.top,
      left: rect.left,
      zIndex: 100,
      position: absolute
    })
    setTimeout(function () {
        me.elStyle = Object.assign({}, me.elStyle, {
          height: me.vueStore.contentRect.bottom - 50;,
          width: me.vueStore.contentRect.right,
          top: me.vueStore.contentRect.top,
          left: me.vueStore.contentRect.left,
        })
    }, 300);
}
```

Comment: This is so useful. How did I get this far through life without knowing it? Thanks